How can I get all mint accounts created after calling createMint()?
From freeCodeCampWeb3's Solana curriculum, build-a-university-nft-certification project:
"getMintAccounts should return all mint accounts owned by the provided payer parameter"
export async function getMintAccounts({ payer }) {
  const mintAccounts = await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(
    payer.publicKey,
    {
      mint,
    },
  );

  console.log(mintAccounts);

  return mintAccounts.value.map(({ account }) => account);
}

For somewhat reason it returns an empty array. Performing a JSONRPC call using method of getProgramAccounts using the TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID shows an account with a pubkey value corresponding to the newly created mint.

import { Connection, GetProgramAccountsFilter } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";

const rpcEndpoint = 'https://example.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/000000/';
const solanaConnection = new Connection(rpcEndpoint);

const walletToQuery = 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY'; //example: vines1vzrYbzLMRdu58ou5XTby4qAqVRLmqo36NKPTg

async function getTokenAccounts(wallet: string, solanaConnection: Connection) {
    const filters:GetProgramAccountsFilter[] = [
        {
          dataSize: 165,    //size of account (bytes)
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 32,     //location of our query in the account (bytes)
            bytes: wallet,  //our search criteria, a base58 encoded string
          },            
        }];
    const accounts = await solanaConnection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, //new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
        {filters: filters}
    );
    console.log(`Found ${accounts.length} token account(s) for wallet ${wallet}.`);
    accounts.forEach((account, i) => {
        //Parse the account data
        const parsedAccountInfo:any = account.account.data;
        const mintAddress:string = parsedAccountInfo["parsed"]["info"]["mint"];
        const tokenBalance: number = parsedAccountInfo["parsed"]["info"]["tokenAmount"]["uiAmount"];
        //Log results
        console.log(`Token Account No. ${i + 1}: ${account.pubkey.toString()}`);
        console.log(`--Token Mint: ${mintAddress}`);
        console.log(`--Token Balance: ${tokenBalance}`);
    });
}
getTokenAccounts(walletToQuery,solanaConnection);

source: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-get-all-tokens-held-by-a-wallet-in-solana
After that if you want get metadata you can use fetchDigitalAsset
Check here:
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/fetch

Still getting an empty array
export async function createMintAccount({ payer }) {
  mint = await createMint(connection, payer, payer.publicKey, payer.publicKey, 0);

  console.log('Mint: ', mint.toBase58());

  return mint;
}

If it helps, this is the function that creates a mint account
